# Powershell - Merging two csv files

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to merge these two CSV files, but having no luck. Can someone please guide me ?

The idea here is that we have a process ('Chrome' in the example below), but that gets stuck frequently on the server. I am trying to write a script that identifies that 'stuck process' - if it runs beyod a certain time, by it's PID and it should notify a few individuals. We can then manually kill the particular process, if needed.

```
$TimeRunning = 300
$ProcessName = "Chrome"
# $ProcessLocation = "ABC"
$Allinfo = "C:\Software\process.csv"
$ProcessRuntime = "C:\Software\process2.csv"
Get-Process $ProcessName > $Allinfo
(Get-Process | Where-Object { ($_.name -eq $ProcessName) }| Format-Table Name,@{label="Running for minutes";expression={[System.Math]::Round(((Get-Date)-$_.StartTime).totalminutes)}})
> $ProcessRuntime
```

[Screenshot of the two CSV files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzpjg.png)
Thanks a bunch everyone.

Comment: PLEASE don't post images of code/data/errors. why? lookee ... Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - THanks heaps, noted for future Lee.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to help a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Used the command below to address it.

```
(Get-Process | Where-Object {($_.name -eq $processname)}| Format-Table Name,ID,@{label="Elapsed time (mins)";expression={[System.Math]::Round(((Get-Date)-$_.StartTime).totalminutes)}}) >$ProcessRuntime
```